# expandable ongoing notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean, expandable

I've got an expandable notification (Jelly Bean, mostly borrowed from the Notifications API Guide), as follows:

```
myId = 1 ;
numUpdates++ ;
myInboxStyle.addLine ("some string") ;
Resources res = context.getResources () ;
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable (R.drawable.ic_launcher) ;

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder (context)
        .setAutoCancel (false)
        .setOngoing (false)
        .setSmallIcon (R.drawable.ic_notify)
        .setLargeIcon (drawable.getBitmap ())
        .setContentTitle ("some update")
        .setStyle (myInboxStyle)
        .setNumber (numUpdates)
        .setContentText ("some text) ;

NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) ;
mNotificationManager.notify (myId, mBuilder.build ()) ;
```

This is working just as I expect: the notification appears, I am able to expand/collapse it, etc.

Now, if I change

```
.setOngoing (true)
```

in the above code I get an ongoing notification (as I want) but it is no longer expandable.

I can't find anything in the Jelly Bean API documentation that suggests that ongoing notifications are not expandable.  Has anyone gotten expandable ongoing notifications to work?  If so, can you point out where my code is in error?

Comment: I just tested this (tweaking AOSP's Notification Builder test to do a dummy BigText style) and it works fine: the notification has flags=0x2 and can still be expanded.

Comment: thanx for checking.  I've only tried it on a VZW Samsung Galaxy Note II (the only Jelly Bean device I have access to), it doesn't work there.

I'd try it in the emulator right now but I'm having problems getting the SdkController app (described here: http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation) working at the moment.  I'll report back if/when I get that working.

But thanx for confirming that it does work for someone.  I'm wondering if this is something Samsung has broken with TouchWiz?

Comment: Just to be clear: until I get the SdkController working I can't do multi-touch on the emulator, and hence, can't test whether the ongoing notification is expandable on the emulator

Comment: In the latest Jelly Bean you can drag downward over the notifications list with a single pointer to expand anything that can be expanded.

Comment: @PaulBiron: Yeah, it's broken in all Samsung devives, so you're not the only one facing this issue.